# Cómo validar un dato de una lista seleccionable

Tags: php, javascript

Cómo saber si al seleccionar un dato de una lista este ya se encuentra en la base de datos comparándolo con la fecha seleccionada de un datepicker, usando javascript!!!!

Comment: ¿ Muéstrenos qué intentó ?

Answer (score 0):

Bueno, si necesitas javascript con jQuery la tienes bastante facil. Algo como:

```
$('#hora').change(function(){
         var valor=$(this).val();
         $.get('../url/para/consultar/'+valor, function(response){
              ...
              # procesar response para ver que devolvio
              if (response.encontrado){
                  alert('La hora ya estaba registrada en la base de datos')
              }else{
                  # hacer otra cosa o registrar la hora
              }
         })
})
```

algo asi deberia funcionar, tambien puedes usar post. Claro que para algo concreto debes tener en cuenta que es necesario enviar la fecha como segundo parametro para hacer la consulta correcta en la base de datos.

Comment: No uses librerías o frameworks que no estén dentro de las etiquetas puestas por el usuario. Trata de responder de acuerdo a las necesidades y herramientas del usuario.

Comment: No veo el problema, la forma más sencilla es usar jQuery, que es básicamente una librería javascript como solicita en el título. En todo caso el usuario tampoco muestra que haya intentado hacer algo con javascript por que en su ejemplo hay solo código PHP.

Comment: No es que sea "un problema" porque ciertamente no lo es, puede funcionar a la perfección. El asunto es que el **puede no querer** usar [tag:jQuery] por diversas razones. Lo mejor es «enfocarse» en lo que el OP usa y dar una respuesta de acuerdo a ello.

Comment: Bueno, si, tienes toda la razon, pero el OP no da señales de saber Javascript, dado que no da ningun ejemplo en su planteo. Es por eso que asumi que seria una buena idea que comience con jQuery, podria dar el ejemplo con Vanilla Javascript, puede que sea funcional, pero seria bueno que el OP tambien sea un poco mas especifico en el ejemplo mostrando cual es su codigo javascript probado.

Comment: Por supuesto, es por eso que uno debe dar una respuesta que no necesite aclaración del OP. En su caso no ha intentado nada; no es conveniente dar una respuesta desde 0 (fíjate en el primer comentario a su pregunta). Tranquilo, ya poco a poco aprenderás las reglas y costumbres del sitio. PD: Si no sabe JavaScript, justamente por eso necesita aprenderlo antes de irse con alguna librería/framework.